# kernel 3.3 panic-dump by root_fs unpack

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm updating kernel on embedded platform to 3.3. 
I have following mem allocation dump on start.
Do you have some hints ? How can I analyse those messages ?

```
populate_rootfs[577] Start: 0x8025c6c4, Size: 0x201557
unpack_to_rootfs[416]
unpack_to_rootfs[425]
vmalloc: allocation failure: 33554432 bytes
swapper: page allocation failure: order:0, mode:0xd2
Call Trace:
[<8000604c>] dump_stack+0x8/0x34
[<800655b4>] warn_alloc_failed+0x108/0x12c
[<80086e20>] __vmalloc_node_range+0x210/0x238
[<80086e78>] __vmalloc_node+0x30/0x3c
[<80086ee0>] vmalloc+0x2c/0x38
[<80246958>] unlzma+0x298/0x1044
[<8023af80>] unpack_to_rootfs+0x1f0/0x388
[<8023b1f8>] populate_rootfs+0x6c/0x29c
[<80000500>] do_one_initcall+0x100/0x1e0
Mem-Info:
Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
active_anon:0 inactive_anon:0 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:0 inactive_file:0 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
 free:6807 slab_reclaimable:6 slab_unreclaimable:81
 mapped:0 shmem:0 pagetables:0 bounce:0
Normal free:27228kB min:0kB low:0kB high:0kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB        
active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB 
isolated(file):0kB present:32512kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB  
shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:24kB slab_unreclaimable:324kB kernel_stack:80kB  
pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0   
all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0
Normal: 3*4kB 4*8kB 1*16kB 3*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 2*256kB 3*512kB 4*1024kB 4*2048kB    
3*4096kB = 27228kB
0 total pagecache pages
0 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
8192 pages RAM
1271 pages reserved
0 pages shared
104 pages non-shared
unpack_to_rootfs[470]
Kernel panic - not syncing: decompressor failed
```

I can compare 3.3 printouts with working 2.6.21 - but I'm not sure where to look for a problem. My first idea is RAM initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to allocate 32MB: `vmalloc: allocation failure: 33554432 bytes`
You have 27MB free: `Normal free:27228kB`
27 < 32

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Ram inicialization/detection goes wrong. 2.6.21 Determined physical RAM map: memory: 08000000 
3.3 Determined physical RAM map: memory: 02000000